# How to put a User Id that's an email address in a connection string

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to connection to a SQL Azure db using a `sys.sysusers` with `name` equal to `"myname@mydoman"`. The issue is that when try with the connection string

```
Data Source=tcp:coolsqldb.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Cool;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=myname@mydoman.com;...
```

I get the exception

```
Cannot open server "mydomain.com" requested by the login.  The login failed.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlIn....
```

I've tried using quotes in `ID=myname@mydoman.com` so that it's `ID='myname@mydoman.com'`, but no luck. Any idea what I can do?

Comment: What authentication do you use? You should use `Active Directory password authentication`.

Comment: Yes - please post the _entire_ connection string

Answer (score 1):

If you create those identities on Azure Active Directory you can then create them as a user of an Azure SQL database.

```
CREATE USER [myname@mydoman.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

Your string connection will then have to change as shown below:

```
string ConnectionString =
@"Data Source=n9lxnyuzhv.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Password; Initial Catalog=testdb;  UID=myname@mydoman.com; PWD=MyPassWord!";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
```

For more information, please visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure) following documentation.